# On number of shifted integer solutions to a linear system

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $M$ be a random diagonally dominant non-singular $3\times 3$ integer matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11}&m_{12}&m_{13}\\
m_{21}&m_{22}&m_{23}\\
m_{31}&m_{32}&m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $|m_{ij}|<T^{8}$ and consider the equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11}&m_{12}&m_{13}\\
m_{21}&m_{22}&m_{23}\\
m_{31}&m_{32}&m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
r_{1}+k_1p\\
r_{2}+k_2q\\
r_{3}+k_3r
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes with size in $[T^9,2T^9]$ and $|r_1|<p,|r_2|<q$ and $|r_3|<r$ holds.

In above $m_{ij},r_i$ are fixed at every $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $p,q,r$ is fixed.

If $|a|,|b|,|c|<T^{3}$ and $|k_1|,|k_2|,|k_3|<T^{2}$ holds and we know there is an **integer** solution $(a,b,c,k_1,k_2,k_3)\in\mathbb Z^6$ to the above system.

> How many additional solutions $(a,b,c,k_1,k_2,k_3)\in\mathbb Z^6$ with $|a|,|b|,|c|<T^{3}$ and $|k_1|,|k_2|,|k_3|<T^{2}$ can we expect?